# RemoteViews setLayoutParams?

Tags: android, view, textview

I would like to set the height of a `TextView` to `WRAP_CONTENT` remotely.

How would I do that, since there is no `remoteviews.setLayoutParams(viewId, param)` function?

I tried `remoteviews.setInt.(viewId, "setHeight", -2)`, but that just sets the height of the `TextView` to zero...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create the `RemoteViews`, pass in a resource ID to the constructor that has the `TextView` set to height set to `wrap_content`. Remember that when you send updates over, you are effectively redrawing the app widget, so you can use your layout files to affect changes that you cannot do via methods on `RemoteViews`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: wrap_content works...almost.  It is fine if the textview's content isn't too large but I want to constrain the height to 25dp.  I.e., the equation would be height <= 25dp but I can't find a way to measure or to control the height.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @PeteH: You could try wrapping the `TextView` in something (e.g., `FrameLayout`) with the `25dp` (or, better, `25sp`) limit, and use `wrap_content` on the `TextView` itself. I'm skeptical that it will meet your request, but it's worth a quick test. Otherwise, I don't have any great ideas -- you might consider asking a separate SO question for it.

Comment: @CommonsWare: thanks for the idea.  the only thing I've found that worked was to count the characters and use that as a crude metric to reduce textSize when there were too many to fit.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you have an idea on how to change the width/height dynamically? I'd like to have the user choose how big the element should be (this means setting an int instead of "wrap_content")  but creating a layout for each possible size does not make sense.

Comment: "I'd like to have the user choose how big the element should be" -- if you indicate that your app widget is resizeable in the metadata, the user can resize the app widget through their home screen (at least for home screen implementations that support it). Then, you just need to use fluid layouts (e.g., `match_parent`) to take up whatever space that you are given. If that is not what you mean, you may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide more details about your scenario.

Comment: @CommonsWare I posted a question with more information. Since this also fits with the title of this question here, I add the link to my question.
[Set ImageView Size in HomeScreen Widget programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29526563/3808452)