# Set ImageView width and height programmatically on a widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using below code to set an image on a widget imageview using remoteview now i want to set height and width to imageview runtime.

```
if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(WidgetActivity1_1.this);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(WidgetActivity1_1.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout1_1);
    Intent configIntent = new Intent(WidgetActivity1_1.this,UpdateWidgetService.class);
    configIntent.putExtra("Appid", appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(WidgetActivity1_1.this, appWidgetId, configIntent, 0);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgviewGrow, R.drawable.flower1);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can set the Layout Params progrematiclly this way:

```
myImageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

or set a number instead.

Image size manipulation sometimes maybe tricky and it's recommended to first get
image layout params, change it and set it back:

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = myImageView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = 30;
layoutParams.height = 30;
myImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

and if you still have a problem to change it's size try to put it inside of a LinearLayout and manipulate the imageView size using the layout params:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
myImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

**Update:** The following posts should help you with what you need:

[RemoteViews setLayoutParams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330847/remoteviews-setlayoutparams)

http://pastebin.com/As3L8xWu

Comment: thanks for reply but it will change imageview heigth width i am using imageview but in widget so we cannot directly access imageview we have to use remoteview as u can see in my post i had set image runtime now in that way i want to set height width in remotview.

Comment: u r seeting imageview layout while in widget you cannot set it you must have to user remotivew and remotview donsnt have an setLayoutPrarms method.

Comment: i have updated my answer with two links that should be helpful to you.

Answer (score -5):

hi try these line to set imageview width and height

```
image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 20;

image_view.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
```

Comment: sorry yar pls read  my post first i am going to set remoteview imageview size not only layout imageivew pls read it.

Comment: check this documentation about Remote view `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#addView%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29`

Answer (score -6):

This should work!

`image.getLayoutParams().height = 90;`

Comment: what your answer adds to for example the one from androidgeek ?