# How to set the size of an imageView

Tags: android

I have 2 imageview in my layout that i define like this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image2" />
```

On the emulater it  works fine, but when i test the application on a tablet the image ramain 320x220.
How can i size the image?

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because many tablets have the same density as phones (mdpi, xhdpi), so the `dp` unit resolves to the same number of pixels.  Set your image size to a `dimens` resource that you can control for different minimum screen sizes. In other words:

**res/layout/your_layout.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image1" />
```

**res/values/dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_width">320dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_height">200dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_width">640dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_height">400dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

The larger values will be used on screens with a smallest-width of 600dp or greater (the average 7" tablet) and the smaller values used everywhere else as the default.  If you want to add more discrete changes, you can create additional `dimens` to override the default values in specific use cases.

Comment: And for smartphone with bigger screen?

Comment: Add as many different dimens definitions that you think you need to satisfy when the image "dp" size should change.  This is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want a different size for [different devices](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html)? like 320x200 for phones but something like 640x400 for tablets?

You'll need to have different layout files.

or you can changing the size/layout/whatever programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171766/29505

Answer (score 0):

To add to Devunwired answer, you also have to add `res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml` for 10" devices. So you should have three:

```
res/values/dimens.xml (standard screen)

res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml (7" devices)

res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml (10" devices)
```