# How to set height of the imageView programatically?

Tags: java, android, imageview, layoutparams

I want to set the height of the image view programatically in gridview. I used below code-

```
imageview.getLayoutParams().height = height;
```

This is working fine in android version 4.3 and higher but not working in android version 4.2 and below. I can't find the issue. Any help please.

ImageView in xml-

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/item_image"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
 android:background="@drawable/top_radius" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set ImageView width and height programmatically on a widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171654/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically-on-a-widget)

Comment: @Neutrino that solution is not working in 4.2 or below thats why i ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
LayoutParams LP = imageview.getLayoutParams();
LP.height = height;
imageview.setLayoutParams(LP)
```

Comment: This also doesn't work in android version 4.2 or lower

Comment: Yes, it should! When do you set this? Try to call invalidate() or requestLayout() on the imageview after you set the new height.

Comment: My ImageView is contains in StaggeredGridView. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to set dimensions of imageview

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
int width = 60;
int height = 60;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
iv.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Comment: @JagveerSinghRajput I can't find any reason why this isn't working below android 4.2

Comment: @JagveerSinghRajput It is included in android API level 1 which means it should work on all versions of android.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html     Share some more details about your imageview code. There could be an issue in some other part of the code

Comment: My ImageView is contains in StaggeredGridView. Is this the problem?

Comment: @JagveerSinghRajput: I do not have much experience on working with a staggeredgridview, but I can tell you that the problem is in that part. I have verified that the above code will work without any error for a simple imageview.

Comment: @JagveerSinghRajput  I recommend you ask a new question now with complete details of your staggeredgridview code and include this keyword in the question's title and question's tags

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ImageView in a LinearLayout and set the height of this LinearLayout like you're doing.