# Editing layout_height programmatically for remoteViews

Tags: android, textview, remoteview

I need to change layout_height for my app widget when the font size is changed. Since it's a widget, it works with remoteViews.

I'm setting textSize like this:

```
protected void setWidgetTextViewSize(float textViewSize)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        remoteViews.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.widgettext1, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textViewSize + 5);
        remoteViews.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.widgettext2, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textViewSize + 5);
    }
    else
    {
        remoteViews.setFloat(R.id.widgettext1, "setTextSize", textViewSize + 5);
        remoteViews.setFloat(R.id.widgettext2, "setTextSize", textViewSize + 5);
    }
}
```

But I didnt find any way to set layout_height for remoteViews. How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RemoteViews setLayoutParams?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330847/remoteviews-setlayoutparams)